# jQuery to add div wrapper to specified elements

Tags: jquery, multiple-columns

I have a CMS generated HTML block. I'd like to add some DIV wrappers to a specific set of elements.

```
<ul id="gform_fields_1">
    <li id="field_1_8" class="gfield">
        <!-- content -->
    </li>
    <li id="field_1_9" class="gfield">
        <!-- content -->
    </li>
    <li id="field_1_10" class="gfield">
        <!-- content -->
    </li>
    <li id="field_1_11" class="gfield">
        <!-- content -->
    </li>
    <li id="field_1_12" class="gfield">
        <!-- content -->
    </li>
    <li id="field_1_13" class="gfield">
        <!-- content -->
    </li>
    <li id="field_1_14" class="gfield">
        <!-- content -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to achieve the following pattern:

```
<ul id="gform_fields_1">
    <div class="wrap">
        <li id="field_1_8" class="gfield">
            <!-- content -->
        </li>
        <li id="field_1_9" class="gfield">
            <!-- content -->
        </li>
        <li id="field_1_10" class="gfield">
            <!-- content -->
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <li id="field_1_11" class="gfield">
            <!-- content -->
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <li id="field_1_12" class="gfield">
            <!-- content -->
        </li>
        <li id="field_1_13" class="gfield">
            <!-- content -->
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

The wraps are for a specific group of elements, for example I'd need #field_1_8, #field_1_19 and #field_1_10 to be enclosed in a DIV, then #field_1_11 wrapped in a DIV, then the remainder. Point is, I'd like to specify the IDs, rather than base it on any logic, so to speak.

`.wrap()` seems like the way to go, to work something like this:

```
$('LIST ALL IDs').wrap('<div class="new" />');
```

Any hints much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since jQuery's selectors syntax is pretty much like CSS, you could simply list your elements like so :

```
$('li#field_1_8, li#field_1_9, li#field_1_10').wrapAll('<div class="new" />')
```

Comment: Thanks, however this will wrap each individual ID in "new", whereas I need to wrap the 3 elements in "new".

Comment: yes.you have to use `wrapAll` to wrap multiple elements in the single div

Answer (score 0):

you can use [slice](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/slice)

```
$('li').slice(0, 3).wrapAll("<div class='wrap'></div>")
$('li').slice(3,4).wrap("<div class='wrap'></div>")
$('li').slice(4,7).wrapAll("<div class='wrap'></div>")
```

jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/NpxxR/

Comment: Thanks. This would work well, but by selecting the element IDs I have more control to do what I need (for example the generated code can include hidden elements, which make the 0,3 / 3,4 etc targeting a bit more tricky)